# Rails, Passenger, Encoding::CompatibilityError in spawn manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, passenger

Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.9
ssl_requirement 1.3.2
passenger 3.0.8

After updating ssl_requirement, when deploying the app I'm now getting `Encoding::CompatibilityError in spawn manager` exceptions

The more details trace indicates that ssl_requirement is involved, during loading of required gems on startup:

```
ssl_requirement.gemspec:11: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/bill/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/ssl_requirement-0db844a72f88/bartt-ssl_requirement.gemspec:11: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/bill/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/ssl_requirement-0db844a72f88/bartt-ssl_requirement.gemspec:11: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
...}, %q{bartt}, %q{Thorben Schröder}]
...                               ^) (process 29902, thread #<Thread:0x00000001274858>):
```

I added the magic encoding tags everywhere in the app, per several google search results, and all my initializers, etc have the proper declarations for UTF-8, but can't make the 500 error go away. What else should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by backing ssl_requirement back down to 1.3.1, then monkey patching in the changes I needed from 1.3.2. Problem solved for now, although I'd like to implement a real solution that doesn't include patching the prior version.